# How to merge two database schemes using toad

Tags: sql-server, merge, toad, schema-compare

I use toad for sql server to compare databases.

Is it possible to merge results between 2 database schema changes?

Answer (score 0):

TOAD for SQL Server (6.1 +) has a neat compare Schema tool, which allows you to compare two databases. It also comes with a wizard that will allow you control how to merge the objects from one database to another.

Without more information about your current setup and what sorts of objects you're trying to merge, there is not much I can do to help you.